# Parsing a JSON array from fopen php

Tags: php, json, fopen

I'm using fopen in php to get a JSON response. How do I then go about using json decode() on what's returned?  This is the code I'm using to get the JSON, but with a URL blocked out. This gives me a JSON.

```
<?php

//$cmd = "ADSFQDS";

$file_handle = fopen("xxurlxx", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle)) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);

print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";
}

fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: Splitting via `=` is a big leap of faith. `"myData":"Because one = two"` could be a valid string in JSON. Don't be surprised if you one day run into some serious parsing issues.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass your read data to the `json_decode()` function.
Assuming that `$line_of_text` is valid **JSON** (so it's not split across multiple lines):

```
$file_handle = fopen("__URL__", "r");

while(!feof($file_handle)){
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $json = json_decode($line_of_text, true);

    print $json["__KEY__"]. "<br>";
}

fclose($file_handle);
```